# Why is there no builder version of get***Map() method on proto3 java builders?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a java project that is using proto3 messages to represent some of our data. We have something that looks like this:

```
message Person {
    // some data is here
}

message Club {
    repeated Person other = 1;
    map<string,Person> roles = 2;
}
```

The generated `Club.Builder` class comes with a convenient `getOtherBuilderList()` which returns a `List<Person.Builder>` that allows you to mutate the elements in place. Why is there no equivalent `getRolesBuilderMap()`?

Comment: Do you not have a `getMutableRoles` method (as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#map-fields))? Is that only for proto2?

Comment: That method is deprecated. It also only returns a mutable `Map<String,Person>` and not the `Map<String,Person.Builder>` that I want.